# I can't seem to get \fbox and \itemize to work together

Tags: lists, boxes, framed, texstudio

I'm trying to place some text inside of a box, here's what I'm writing that is not working:

```
\fbox{The \textit{two-step} model of XMCD:
\begin{itemize}
\item[In the \textit{first step}, circularly polarized X-rays generate photoelectrons
with a spin and/or orbital momentum from a localized atomic inner shell.]
\item[In the \textit{second step}, the 3d shell serves as the detector of the spin or
orbital momentum of the photoelectron. For maximum effect, the photon spin needs to be
aligned with the magnetization direction.]
\end{itemize}
}
```

It doesn't build and compile, the best I've gotten is a box around the very first sentence and then some weird formatting issues... TexStudio doesn't like me placing the closing bracket for `\fbox` anywhere else.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can enclose your text with `\parbox` first then `\fbox`, such that:

```
\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{The \textit{two-step} model of XMCD:
\begin{itemize}
\item In the \textit{first step}, circularly polarized X-rays generate photoelectrons with a spin and/or orbital momentum from a localized atomic inner shell.
\item In the \textit{second step}, the 3d shell serves as the detector of the spin or orbital momentum of the photoelectron. For maximum effect, the photon spin needs to be aligned with the magnetization direction.
\end{itemize}}}
```

produces:[image]

In addition, don't enclose text of item with bracket `[]`.

Comment: You should consider using a width of `\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule` to avoid the size of the box to extend over the text block boundary.

Answer (score 18):

[Francis already gave an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125716/6563) with \parbox. Werner gave a comment for boundaries.

I would recommend to use the framed-environment:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{framed} 

\begin{document}

\section{With parbox}

\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{The \textit{two-step} model of XMCD:
\begin{itemize}
\item In the \textit{first step}, circularly polarized X-rays generate photoelectrons with a spin and/or orbital momentum from a localized atomic inner shell.
\item In the \textit{second step}, the 3d shell serves as the detector of the spin or orbital momentum of the photoelectron. For maximum effect, the photon spin needs to be aligned with the magnetization direction.
\end{itemize}}}

\section{framed}

\begin{framed}
The \textit{two-step} model of XMCD:
\begin{itemize}
\item In the \textit{first step}, circularly polarized X-rays generate photoelectrons with a spin and/or orbital momentum from a localized atomic inner shell.
\item In the \textit{second step}, the 3d shell serves as the detector of the spin or orbital momentum of the photoelectron. For maximum effect, the photon spin needs to be aligned with the magnetization direction.
\end{itemize}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

With the framed-environment you get a nicer look:

[image: result of code example]

Beside the better result, also the TeX-source looks more *Markup*-like.

Comment: What do you mean by "markup"?

Comment: You don't describe how it should look like, but describe what you want. If you would make it even more markup-like, you should define a new environment _modeldescription_. The decision, how _modeldescription_ should look like is defined later.

Answer (score 12):

For their flexibility in the format, I suggest take a look to the packages `tcolorbox`, `mdframed`, or even `bclogo`, to make from simple frames with sharp corners to really fancy boxes. Run  `texdoc tcolorbox`, `texdoc mdframed` and `texdoc bclogo`to see a lot of options. Some examples:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\section{With tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
colframe=blue!25,
colback=blue!10,
coltitle=blue!20!black,  
fonttitle=\bfseries,
adjusted title=The {\em two-step} model of XMCD:]
\begin{itemize}
\item In the \textit{first step}, circularly polarized X-rays generate photoelectrons with a spin and/or orbital momentum from a localized atomic inner shell.
\item In the \textit{second step}, the 3d shell serves as the detector of the spin or orbital momentum of the photoelectron. For maximum effect, the photon spin needs to be aligned with the magnetization direction.
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}

\section{With mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[
linecolor=black!40,
outerlinewidth=1pt,
roundcorner=.5em,
innertopmargin=1ex,
innerbottommargin=.5\baselineskip,
innerrightmargin=1em,
innerleftmargin=1em,
backgroundcolor=blue!10,
%userdefinedwidth=1\textwidth,
shadow=true,
shadowsize=6,
shadowcolor=black!20,
frametitle={The \textit{two-step} model of XMCD:},
frametitlebackgroundcolor=cyan!40,
frametitlerulewidth=10pt
]

\begin{itemize}
\item In the \textit{first step}, circularly polarized X-rays generate photoelectrons with a spin and/or orbital momentum from a localized atomic inner shell.
\item In the \textit{second step}, the 3d shell serves as the detector of the spin or orbital momentum of the photoelectron. For maximum effect, the photon spin needs to be aligned with the magnetization direction.
\end{itemize}
\end{mdframed}

\section{With bclogo}

\renewcommand\logowidth{16pt}
\begin{bclogo}[
couleur = blue!10,
marge=20,
cadreTitre = true, 
arrondi = 0.3, 
epBarre=3.5,
logo = \bcnucleaire, 
couleurBarre = red!80!blue!60,
ombre=true,
couleurOmbre = blue!20!black!20,
]
{The \textit{two-step} model of XMCD:}
\bigskip
\begin{itemize}
\item In the \textit{first step}, circularly polarized X-rays generate photoelectrons with a spin and/or orbital momentum from a localized atomic inner shell.
\item In the \textit{second step}, the 3d shell serves as the detector of the spin or orbital momentum of the photoelectron. For maximum effect, the photon spin needs to be aligned with the magnetization direction.
\end{itemize}
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```