# \framebox as \labelenumi

Tags: lists, framed, labels

for a questionaire where possible answers appear as enumerate entries, I'm trying to have one document with plain squares and one where the squares are filled with either W or F.

I tried

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{{\framebox[1.5em][c]{\phantom{W}}} \hspace{2ex} \alph{enumi})}
```

but it doesn't work.
It's kinda the other way around of [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125715/i-cant-seem-to-get-fbox-and-itemize-to-work-together).

EDIT: Heres the LWE as asked for:

    `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    % european article
    %Neue Deutsche Rechtschreibung und Silbentrennung
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    %Auswahl der deutschen Varianten aller Befehle, z.B. \blindtext
    \selectlanguage{ngerman}
    % Schreiben von Umlauten auf einem LINUX-System
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    % Math-Paket der American Mathematical Society
    \usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,amsbsy,amsthm,amsxtra}
    % Geometrie und vor allem margins des Papier angleichen
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    % Anzeige Seite n von m
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    % Anpassung von Kopf- und Fußzeile
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    % Schriftgröße variieren
    \usepackage{txfonts}
    % Änderung der Titel-Formatierung
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    % Änderung des Einzugs der Aufzählung
    \usepackage{enumitem}`

```
% Linksbündig
\raggedright
% Horizontale Einrückung zu Beginn neuer Absätze
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
% Vertikaler Abstand zwischen Absätzen
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
% Formattierung der section-Titel auf die Aufgaben
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textbf{Aufgabe~\arabic{section}}}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1ex}{0ex}
% Änderung der enumerate-Labels auf kleine Buchstaben

\newcommand{\Witem}{%
\refstepcounter{enumi}% Step enumerate counter
\item[{\framebox[1.5em]{W}\hspace{2ex}\alph{enumi}})]}
\newcommand{\Fitem}{%
\refstepcounter{enumi}% Step enumerate counter
\item[{\framebox[1.5em]{F}\hspace{2ex}\alph{enumi}})]}
\newcommand{\Bitem}{%
\refstepcounter{enumi}% Step enumerate counter
\item[{\framebox[1.5em]{\phantom{W}}\hspace{2ex}\alph{enumi}})]}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{{\framebox[1.5em][c]{\phantom{W}}} \hspace{2ex}     \alph{enumi})}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=2cm}
%~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~
\begin{document}

% ~=~=~ Frage 1 ~=~=~
\section{Abbildungen, Rang, Injektivität/Surjektivität/Bijektivität}
Sei $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 4 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$.\quad Zeige oder widerlege für $A$ folgende Aussagen\\

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\text{rang}(A)=2$
\Witem Die durch $A$ beschriebene lineare Abbildung ist injektiv.
\item Die durch $A$ beschriebene lineare Abbildung ist surjektiv.
\item Die durch $A$ beschriebene lineare Abbildung ist bijektiv.
\end{enumerate}

% ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about, instead of teasing us with little code snippets, you provide something more substantial in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so we have something to play with?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Reiterating @Werner's suggestion: while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: In my article class document I use `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{{\Huge $\Box$} \hspace{2ex} \alph{enumi})}` so far but it's ugly.
I cannot change it locally via `\item[{\framebox[1.5em][c]{W}}] itemtext `

Comment: @Yeru Please edit your question and provide an MWE as others have requested.

Comment: MWE added,
strangely, an isolated one works, somehow my combination in the original file doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're not really interested in an overlay specification. Then you can define a `\Witem` and `\Fitem` to draw the blocks you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\Witem}{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}% Step enumerate counter
  \item[{\framebox[1.5em]{W}\hspace{2ex}\theenumi}.]}
\newcommand{\Fitem}{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}% Step enumerate counter
  \item[{\framebox[1.5em]{F}\hspace{2ex}\theenumi}.]}
\newcommand{\Bitem}{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}% Step enumerate counter
  \item[{\framebox[1.5em]{\phantom{W}}\hspace{2ex}\theenumi}.]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
      An regular item

    \Witem
      A \alert{true} item

    \item
      A regular item

    \Fitem
      A \alert{false} item

    \Bitem
      A \alert{block} item
  \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Werner, thanks for the ideas with `\newcommand`, definitely will be useful.
Yet, it works in beamer class but not in article!

Comment: @Yeru: You will recall that your [previous revision](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/187375/4) included an example using [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). This goes to show that you should heed the suggestions of people on this site when it comes to producing a minimal example. Is the output what you want, but just in the `article` class?