# Special sections in the document

Tags: block

I have a plan to make special sections in the document. For example:

- Good news. While you're reading a book, you'll see inset block that gives you some additional information.
- Example. While you reading a book, you can read example from the author.
- Personal story. Some personal story from the author of the book.

I don't know the right name for these blocks. Usually it's similar to something you have with bulb and some additional text in "For Dummies" series.

How can I do it in Latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. See the `bclogo`, `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` packages... they provide more or less what you want

Comment: Supporting the  Christian's comment: a little [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125762/11604).

Comment: More examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66820/how-to-create-highlight-boxes-in-latex/66822#66822 (duplicate?)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. (and Fran as well): Both links show  nice examples and it might be a duplicate really, but at the moment, we have no idea how those boxes should look like...