# Creating box on long enumeration

Tags: parbox, box, fbox

Hello so I want to make a box outside of enumeration:

```
\noindent\fbox{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Matriks contoh merupakan matriks berukuran 2x2 seperti berikut: \\
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    5 & 0\\ 
    0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$
    \item Kemudian mencari matriks S dengan menggunakan rumus 2.2 hingga 2.3.\\
    $AA^T$=
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    5 & 0\\ 
    0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$
    *
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 5
    \end{pmatrix}$
    = 
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 0\\ 
    0 & 4
    \end{pmatrix}$ \\\\
    $det(AA^T-\lambda \textit{I}) = 0$\\\\
    det
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 0\\ 
    0 & 4
    \end{pmatrix}$
    - $\lambda$
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$
    = 0 \\

    det
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 0\\ 
    0 & 4
    \end{pmatrix}$
    - 
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda & 0\\ 
    0 & \lambda
    \end{pmatrix}$
    = 0 \\

    det
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    4-\lambda & 0\\ 
    0 & 4-\lambda
    \end{pmatrix}$
    = 0 \\

    ...

    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    $
\end{enumerate}
}}
```

But then I add the fbox and parbox like in [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125715/i-cant-seem-to-get-fbox-and-itemize-to-work-together)  but it seems that the content kinda hidden at the end of the first page of the box. Any help?

Comment: Please add a compilable MWE.

Answer (score 2):

Existing suggestion works fine, please refer:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{framed,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Matriks contoh merupakan matriks berukuran 2x2 seperti berikut: \\
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    5 & 0\\ 
    0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$
    \item Kemudian mencari matriks S dengan menggunakan rumus 2.2 hingga 2.3.\\
    $AA^T$=
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    5 & 0\\ 
    0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$
    *
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 5
    \end{pmatrix}$
    = 
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 0\\ 
    0 & 4
    \end{pmatrix}$ \\\\
    $det(AA^T-\lambda \textit{I}) = 0$\\\\
    det
    $\begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 0\\ 
    0 & 4
    \end{pmatrix}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you,  I thought I cannot use the frame because there is error. it seems my document adds the "use package" in separates documment so i dont know i must include it.

Comment: @BobNathanZeonBe Glad to know that you able to fix the error...Thanks for your reply...

Comment: It's my pleasure ^